# Display specific texts if the first 4 children meet the requirements, with Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-table, children

I have a table with multiple rows and columns. What I want is this: if first 4 of 5 children have specific class, then append a specific text to another div. Else, not. And I am stucked with this code. Any help will be appreciated:

```
$('table > tbody tr').each(function() {
var counter = 0;
 var ccc;
    $('td.form a:nth-child(1), td.form a:nth-child(2), td.form a:nth-child(3),td.form a:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
        if(( $(this).hasClass("form-win") ) || ( $(this).hasClass("form-loss") )) { 
            $(this).css('background','red');
            counter++;
            ccc = $(this).closest('tr.team_rank').find('td.team a').text();
            $('results').append(ccc);
            }
              else {
            $(this).css('background','blue');
        }
    });    
});
```

I have updated my pen also, to visualize the table:
https://codepen.io/tudor-taranu/pen/gZrmKR

```js
$('table > tbody tr').each(function() {
var counter = 0;
 var ccc;
    $('td.form a:nth-child(1), td.form a:nth-child(2), td.form a:nth-child(3),td.form a:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
        if(( $(this).hasClass("form-win") ) || ( $(this).hasClass("form-loss") )) { 
            $(this).css('background','red');
            counter++;
            ccc = $(this).closest('tr.team_rank').find('td.team a').text();
            $('results').append(ccc);
            }
              else {
            $(this).css('background','blue');
        }
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="leaguetable sortable table detailed-table" id="page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_7_block_competition_league_table_1_table" data-round_id="48876">     
  <thead>       
    <tr class="sub-head">         
      <th title="Loc" class="sortasc sortdefaultasc">#
      </th>                  
      <th class="text team sortdefaultasc">team
      </th>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      <th class="form nosort">last 5
      </th>                 
    </tr>     
  </thead>     
  <tbody>       
    <tr class="odd   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_1824" data-team_id="1824">         
      <td class="rank rank-light-green">1
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="CFR Cluj">CFR Cluj
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="CFR Cluj - Gaz Metan Mediaş 2 - 2" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Dinamo Bucureşti - CFR Cluj 0 - 3" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="CFR Cluj - Voluntari 5 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Concordia Chiajna - CFR Cluj 0 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="CFR Cluj - Dunărea Călăraşi 0 - 0">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>              
    <tr class="odd   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_25281" data-team_id="25281">         
      <td class="rank rank-light-green">3
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Universitatea Craiova">Universitatea …
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Universitatea Craiova - Voluntari 3 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Concordia Chiajna - Universitatea Craiova 1 - 3" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Universitatea Craiova - Dunărea Călăraşi 1 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Botoşani - Universitatea Craiova 2 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="Universitatea Craiova - Sepsi 1 - 1">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="even   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_13720" data-team_id="13720">         
      <td class="rank rank-light-green">4
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Viitorul">Viitorul
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="FCSB - Viitorul 2 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Gaz Metan Mediaş - Viitorul 2 - 2" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Viitorul - Dinamo Bucureşti 4 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Voluntari - Viitorul 1 - 2" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="Viitorul - Concordia Chiajna 0 - 0">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="odd   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_1827" data-team_id="1827">         
      <td class="rank rank-light-green">5
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Gaz Metan Mediaş">Gaz Metan Mediaş
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="CFR Cluj - Gaz Metan Mediaş 2 - 2" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Gaz Metan Mediaş - Viitorul 2 - 2" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="FCSB - Gaz Metan Mediaş 2 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Dinamo Bucureşti - Gaz Metan Mediaş 1 - 1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win last" title="Gaz Metan Mediaş - Voluntari 2 - 0">W
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>                                   
    <tr class="even   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_37490" data-team_id="37490">         
      <td class="rank rank-orange">10
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Hermannstadt">Hermannstadt
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Hermannstadt - Dinamo Bucureşti 1 - 1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Voluntari - Hermannstadt 2 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Hermannstadt - Concordia Chiajna 2 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Dunărea Călăraşi - Hermannstadt 0 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="Hermannstadt - Botoşani 1 - 1">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="odd   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_1775" data-team_id="1775">         
      <td class="rank rank-orange">11
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Dinamo Bucureşti">Dinamo Bucureşti
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Hermannstadt - Dinamo Bucureşti 1 - 1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Dinamo Bucureşti - CFR Cluj 0 - 3" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Viitorul - Dinamo Bucureşti 4 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Dinamo Bucureşti - Gaz Metan Mediaş 1 - 1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="Dinamo Bucureşti - FCSB 1 - 1">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="even   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_9221" data-team_id="9221">         
      <td class="rank rank-orange">12
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Dunărea Călăraşi">Dunărea Călăraşi
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Politehnica Iași - Dunărea Călăraşi 1 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Dunărea Călăraşi - Astra 1 - 2" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Universitatea Craiova - Dunărea Călăraşi 1 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Dunărea Călăraşi - Hermannstadt 0 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="CFR Cluj - Dunărea Călăraşi 0 - 0">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="odd   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_9088" data-team_id="9088">         
      <td class="rank rank-orange">13
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Concordia Chiajna">Concordia Chiajna
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Concordia Chiajna - Politehnica Iași 3 - 6" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Astra - Concordia Chiajna 3 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Concordia Chiajna - Universitatea Craiova 1 - 3" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Hermannstadt - Concordia Chiajna 2 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss last" title="Concordia Chiajna - CFR Cluj 0 - 1">L
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="even   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_11607" data-team_id="11607">         
      <td class="rank rank-orange">14
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Voluntari">Voluntari
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Universitatea Craiova - Voluntari 3 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Voluntari - Hermannstadt 2 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="CFR Cluj - Voluntari 5 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Voluntari - Viitorul 1 - 2" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss last" title="Gaz Metan Mediaş - Voluntari 2 - 0">L
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>     
  </tbody>        
</table>
<br>
<div class="results">RESULT: 
</div>
```

Comment: You aren't checking row specific cells. Beyond that it's not entirely clear what your specific requirements are

Comment: If you are looking on the pen, I want this: if the first 4 childs are red from the last TD, then APPEND the text from the middle, in the external DIV. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot figure it what

Comment: just to clarify: for all the rows, if the first 4 childs are 'red', doesn't matter if they are W, D or L, then display the name of that team in the results DIV?... in case of multiple such rows, multiple names to be displayed in results DIV?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. If the first 4 are red, display the result in the external div as this: RESULTS: TEAM 1, TEAM 2, TEAM 3, ETC. Red means W or L, without D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution to your problem: in every `tr`, you have to check if every `form-icon` has class `form-win` or `form-loss` (your red ones) and add +1 to counter if there are. If the counter reach 4 you know that the first 4 `form-icon` are red and you can add that team to `results` div.

This is the script, all commented to better understand (I tried to use the code you had already written):

```
$('table > tbody tr').each(function () {
    var counter = 0; /* reset counter to every tr loop */
    var ccc = $(this).closest('tr.team_rank').find('td.team a').text(); /* put in ccc the name of team every tr */
    $(".form-icon", $(this)).each(function () {

        if ($(this).hasClass("form-win") || $(this).hasClass("form-loss")) {
            counter++ /*if a form-icon has the class form-win or form-loss (the red ones) add +1 to counter */
        } else {
            return false; /* if those classes there aren't exit from loop */
        }

        if (counter == 4) {
            $('.results').append(ccc + ", "); /*if the counter is equals to 4 add the team to .result div */
        }
    });
});
```

And this is that script in action.

```js
$('table > tbody tr').each(function () {
 var counter = 0; /* reset counter to every tr loop */
 var ccc = $(this).closest('tr.team_rank').find('td.team a').text(); /* put in ccc the name of team every tr */
 $(".form-icon", $(this)).each(function () {

  if ($(this).hasClass("form-win") || $(this).hasClass("form-loss")) {
   counter++ /*if a form-icon has the class form-win or form-loss (the red ones) add +1 to counter */
  } else {
   return false; /* if those classes there aren't exit from loop */
  }

  if (counter == 4) {
   $('.results').append(ccc + ", "); /*if the counter is equals to 4 add the team to .result div */
  }
 });
});

/* This script removes last ', ' from your teams's string. You can remove it, if you don't need it */
$('.results').text(function (_, txt) {
 return txt.slice(0, -2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="leaguetable sortable table detailed-table" id="page_competition_1_block_competition_tables_7_block_competition_league_table_1_table" data-round_id="48876">     
  <thead>       
    <tr class="sub-head">         
      <th title="Loc" class="sortasc sortdefaultasc">#
      </th>                  
      <th class="text team sortdefaultasc">team
      </th>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      <th class="form nosort">last 5
      </th>                 
    </tr>     
  </thead>     
  <tbody>       
    <tr class="odd   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_1824" data-team_id="1824">         
      <td class="rank rank-light-green">1
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="CFR Cluj">CFR Cluj
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="CFR Cluj - Gaz Metan Mediaş 2 - 2" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Dinamo Bucureşti - CFR Cluj 0 - 3" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="CFR Cluj - Voluntari 5 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Concordia Chiajna - CFR Cluj 0 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="CFR Cluj - Dunărea Călăraşi 0 - 0">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>              
    <tr class="odd   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_25281" data-team_id="25281">         
      <td class="rank rank-light-green">3
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Universitatea Craiova">Universitatea …
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Universitatea Craiova - Voluntari 3 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Concordia Chiajna - Universitatea Craiova 1 - 3" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Universitatea Craiova - Dunărea Călăraşi 1 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Botoşani - Universitatea Craiova 2 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="Universitatea Craiova - Sepsi 1 - 1">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="even   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_13720" data-team_id="13720">         
      <td class="rank rank-light-green">4
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Viitorul">Viitorul
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="FCSB - Viitorul 2 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Gaz Metan Mediaş - Viitorul 2 - 2" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Viitorul - Dinamo Bucureşti 4 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Voluntari - Viitorul 1 - 2" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="Viitorul - Concordia Chiajna 0 - 0">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="odd   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_1827" data-team_id="1827">         
      <td class="rank rank-light-green">5
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Gaz Metan Mediaş">Gaz Metan Mediaş
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="CFR Cluj - Gaz Metan Mediaş 2 - 2" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Gaz Metan Mediaş - Viitorul 2 - 2" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="FCSB - Gaz Metan Mediaş 2 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Dinamo Bucureşti - Gaz Metan Mediaş 1 - 1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win last" title="Gaz Metan Mediaş - Voluntari 2 - 0">W
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>                                   
    <tr class="even   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_37490" data-team_id="37490">         
      <td class="rank rank-orange">10
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Hermannstadt">Hermannstadt
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Hermannstadt - Dinamo Bucureşti 1 - 1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Voluntari - Hermannstadt 2 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Hermannstadt - Concordia Chiajna 2 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Dunărea Călăraşi - Hermannstadt 0 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="Hermannstadt - Botoşani 1 - 1">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="odd   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_1775" data-team_id="1775">         
      <td class="rank rank-orange">11
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Dinamo Bucureşti">Dinamo Bucureşti
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Hermannstadt - Dinamo Bucureşti 1 - 1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Dinamo Bucureşti - CFR Cluj 0 - 3" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Viitorul - Dinamo Bucureşti 4 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw" title="Dinamo Bucureşti - Gaz Metan Mediaş 1 - 1" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">D
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="Dinamo Bucureşti - FCSB 1 - 1">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="even   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_9221" data-team_id="9221">         
      <td class="rank rank-orange">12
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Dunărea Călăraşi">Dunărea Călăraşi
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Politehnica Iași - Dunărea Călăraşi 1 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Dunărea Călăraşi - Astra 1 - 2" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Universitatea Craiova - Dunărea Călăraşi 1 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Dunărea Călăraşi - Hermannstadt 0 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-draw last" title="CFR Cluj - Dunărea Călăraşi 0 - 0">D
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>       
    <tr class="odd   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_9088" data-team_id="9088">         
      <td class="rank rank-orange">13
      </td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Concordia Chiajna">Concordia Chiajna
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Concordia Chiajna - Politehnica Iași 3 - 6" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Astra - Concordia Chiajna 3 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Concordia Chiajna - Universitatea Craiova 1 - 3" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Hermannstadt - Concordia Chiajna 2 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss last" title="Concordia Chiajna - CFR Cluj 0 - 1">L
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>  


    <tr class="even   team_rank" id="team_rank_row_11607" data-team_id="11607">         
      <td class="rank rank-orange">14</td>                  
      <td class="text team large-link">
        <a title="Voluntari">Voluntari
        </a>
      </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      <td class="form">           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Universitatea Craiova - Voluntari 3 - 1" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-win" title="Voluntari - Hermannstadt 2 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">W
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="CFR Cluj - Voluntari 5 - 0" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss" title="Voluntari - Viitorul 1 - 2" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">L
        </a>           
        <a class="form-icon form-loss last" title="Gaz Metan Mediaş - Voluntari 2 - 0">L
        </a>         
      </td>                 
    </tr>     
  </tbody>        
</table>
<br>
<div class="results">RESULT: 
</div>
```